# How to filter and displayed 'many to many' elements in Django

Tags: django, django-filter, manytomanyfield

I'm learning django and in my project can't figure out how properly get and displayed elements from many to many relation on deck detail page.

**model.py**

```
class Card(models.Model):
    def upload_path(self, filename):
        return os.path.join('cards/', filename)

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path)
    card_num = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')
    desc = models.TextField(max_length=500, default='')
    card_class = models.OneToOneField(CardClass, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, default='')
    cost = models.OneToOneField(Cost, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, default='')
    card_type = models.OneToOneField(CardType, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, default='')
    rarity = models.OneToOneField(Rarity, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, default='')
    resource = models.IntegerField(default=None)
    attack = models.IntegerField(default=None)
    defence = models.IntegerField(default=None)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('card:cardPageDetail', args=[self.name])


class Deck(models.Model):

    def upload_path(self, filename):
        return os.path.join('decks/', filename)

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cards_list = models.ManyToManyField(Card, related_name='cards_list')
    deck_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')
    price = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('card:deckPageDetail', args=[self.name])
```

**views.py**

```
def deckPageDetail(request, name):
    deck=get_object_or_404(Deck, name=name)
    cards_all = Card.objects.all()
    queryset = cards_all.objects.filter(cards_list__in=deck.deck_id)
    print(queryset)
    context = {
        'deck': deck,
        'cards_in_deck': queryset,
    }
    return render(request, 'landing/deck_detail.html', context)
```

I tried few solutions based on stackoverflow and uncle google, but without results.I will be grateful for help.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to access the *card_list* attribute of your deck.

```
deck = Deck.objects.get(id=1)
for card in deck.cards_list.all():
    print(card)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for an answer. It is working for specific deck id. How I can change it to recognize in deck = Deck.objects.get(id=1) which deck is used and what id it has, and based on that displayed list of cards. It's probably a newbie question, but I'm just learning. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You already have the deck with the M2M so you can access the card list directly in the template. First, let's clean up the code that isn't required.

```
def deckPageDetail(request, name):
    deck=get_object_or_404(Deck, name=name)
    context = {
        'deck': deck,
    }
    return render(request, 'landing/deck_detail.html', context)
```

Then inside of your `landing/deck_detail.html` template you can loop over the cards with the code below.

```
{% for card in deck.cards_list.all %}
    {{ card }}
{% endfor %}
```

and if you want to access the cards information

```
{% for card in deck.cards_list.all %}
    {{ card }} {{ card.image.url }} {{ card.card_num }}
{% endfor %}
```

and just in case you wanted it in the view

```
def deckPageDetail(request, name):
    deck=get_object_or_404(Deck, name=name)
    queryset = deck.cards_list.all()
    print(queryset)
    context = {
        'deck': deck,
        'cards_in_deck': queryset,
    }
    return render(request, 'landing/deck_detail.html', context)
```